# How to get the length of a scroll move

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I get the length of scroll by dragging in a tableview, I want to execute a function inside `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` but only when the user scroll long, not when the user just touch the screen and the scroll bar moves by 1 mm, I need to know how match the scroll bar move so I can put a condition on that

Comment: `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` is used to react to the initial detection of a swipe/pan gesture. You can consider using `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` to react on user reaching the next cell or if you want a exact scroll amount reaction you can use `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` to calculate distant the content view moved or `touchesMoved(_:with:)` to calculate distant of the swipe

Comment: yes I wana calculate the amount of scroll, how can I use this `touchesMoved(_:with:)` inside `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` ?

Comment: no, I gave you two options, `scrollViewDidScroll` is a scrollViewDelegate method which is usable once you make your view controller(VC) the delegate of your tableView. `touchesMoved` is a method you can override in your VC to detect touches on the screen. They are not meant to be used together.

Comment: Ok, I used already `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, I thought that `touchesMoved(_:with:)` will be more useful, but thanks for you time :)

Comment: there is a difference, `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` only fires once at the start of the gesture and therefore no enough for your use. `scrollViewDidScroll` continuously gets called as the user scroll. Just store the initial content offset of your tableview on `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and check with the current offset in `scrollViewDidScroll` and perform you codes once there is enough movement.

Comment: yes, I figure it out and that is what I did !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollViewWillBeginDragging` only fires once at the start of the gesture. `scrollViewDidScroll` continuously gets called as the user scroll. Just store the initial content offset of your tableview on `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and check with the current offset in `scrollViewDidScroll` and perform you codes once there is enough movement.

```
   var currentPosition : CGFloat!

override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    currentPosition = tableView.contentOffset.y
}


override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let amoutOfScroll = abs(tableView.contentOffset.y - currentPosition) // abs return absulote value, just to avoid getting nagative values

    let scrollLenght = 25 // the length of scroling I need

    if amoutOfScroll > scrollLenght { 

        // code

    }
}
```